# Login doesn't work in 1st attempt on live server

Tags: php, authentication

I am new in PHP and I made a simple login page.It works fine on local server but doesn't works  on first attempt on live server. After the 1st attempt then does works. I think the problem is in sessions, but I unable to figure out the exact problem. Once again describe in detail (In any Browser after 1st attempt it shows same login page instead of redirect on main.php. then after 2nd attempt it redirects on main.php page and works fine until browser has been running. Next day again it needs 2 attempts when wrong credentials works fine from the 1st attempt but with correct credentials it requires 2 attempt.)

```
**login.php**
<form action="login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return loginvalidate()" name="loginfrm">
<table width="600" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td><input name="txtusername" type="text" maxlength="15" id="txtusername"/></td> 
    <span id="message"></span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> Minimum 5 alphanumeric letters (a-z A-Z 0-9)</td></tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Password</td>

    <td><input name="txtpass" type="password" maxlength="7" />

    <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> Minimum 5 alphanumeric letters (a-z A-Z 0-9)</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td><input type="submit" name="submit"/></td>

  </tr>

   <tr>

    <td><a href="">Forget password?</a></td>

    <td><a href="registration.php">New Register</a></td>

  </tr>

  </table>

</form>



<?PHP

session_start();
function login()
{
include ("includes/dbConfig.php");
$uname = $_POST["txtusername"];
$pass = $_POST["txtpass"];
$uname = stripslashes($uname); 
$pass =  stripslashes($pass);
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE username = '$uname' and password = '$pass'");
if(mysql_num_rows($log)==1)
{
  $_SESSION["username"] = $uname;
  //header("location: main.php");
  echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='main.php'</script>");                 
}
else
{
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login Fail - Check Username and password')</script>";
}
mysql_close($ms);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   login();
} 
?>
```

**main.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$temp = $_SESSION["username"];
echo "$temp";
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
header('Location: admin.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Comment: The `mysql_` extension is deprecated. Please use `mysqli_` with prepared statements or PDO instead.

Comment: It's a bad idea to store the passwords unencrypted. If your database gets compromised, everyone's passwords will be plainly visible.

Answer (score 0):

You put session_start(); at top of page but not in login function.use this code.

```
 **login.php**  

<?PHP
function login()
{
include ("includes/dbConfig.php");
$uname = $_POST["txtusername"];
$pass = $_POST["txtpass"];
$uname = stripslashes($uname); 
$pass =  stripslashes($pass);
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE username = '$uname' and password = '$pass'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($log)==1)
    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["username"] = $uname;
        //header("location: main.php");
    echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='main.php'</script>");               
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login Fail - Check Username and password')</script>";

    }
mysql_close($ms);
}

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    login();
 } 
?>
```

Comment: put include ("includes/dbConfig.php"); at top of login.php

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion but still problem remain same and generated 1 more error on local server where it did not recognize ms variable "mysql_close($ms);"  where i closed the connection.