# User already exist script using ajax always return user already taken message

Tags: php, ajax

I am new in PHP and I made simple login page where I applied a  ajax script to check "user already exist or not".
but script always returns me "user already taken" message whether I inserted new value. I checked whole code I cannot get the clue where I did mistake.

```
admin.php
==========
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="usernameavail.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="admin.php" method="post" name="loginfrm">
<table width="600" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td><input name="txtusername" type="text" maxlength="15" id="txtusername" /></td>
          <span id="message"></span>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>

     </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input name="txtpass" type="password" maxlength="7" />
    <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> Minimum 5 alphanumeric 
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit"/></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><a href="">Forget password?</a></td>
      <td><a href="registration.php">New Register</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
=========
 check.php
 =========
 <?php
  include ("includes/dbConfig.php");
  $username=$_POST["txtusername"];
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from logininfo where username='$username' ");
  $find=mysql_num_rows($query);
  echo $find;
 ?>
 ===================   
 usernameavail.js
 ===================
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 $("#txtusername").change(function()
 {
 $("#message").html("<img src='images/ajax-loading.gif' /> checking...");
 var username= $("#txtusername").val();
 $.ajax(
 {
 type:"post",
 url:"check.php",
 data:"username="+username,success:function(data)
 {
 if(data==0)
 {
 $("#message").html("<img src='images/accept.png' /> Username available");
 }
 else
 {
 $("#message").html("<img src='images/error.png' /> Username already taken");
 }
 }
 });
 });
 });
```

Comment: How will `if(data==0)` ever be true?

Comment: Check response in firebug?? One more tip always use response named variable in the success function that will help you in coding and debugging too

Answer (score 0):

in javascript file, put quotes for zero

```
if(data == '0')
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, it would be more useful if it explained *why* the quotes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
    $.ajax(
 {
 type:"post",
 url:"check.php",
 data:"username="+username
```

this

```
 $.ajax(
 {
 type:"post",
 url:"check.php",
 data: username:username
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if in `check.php` you replace

```
echo $find;
```

with

```
if($find>0)
 {
   echo 'something';
 }
```

And in your ajax call check if data has value.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
'data:"username="+username,success:function(data)'
```

to

```
data:{"txtusername":username},success:function(data)
```

And this will work

Comment: wow. you are a genius man. If you have time then plz check one more query of mine [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785755/login-doesnt-work-in-1st-attempt-on-live-server)

Comment: Hi, Plz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785755/login-doesnt-work-in-1st-attempt-on-live-server/20785923?noredirect=1#comment31292061_20785923